# What is the name of a pair of brackets inside a C# function that only exists for an extra level of scope?

Tags: c#, .net

Take as an example the following C# function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r = new Random();
        {
            var i = r.Next(); ;
            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
        }

        var action = new Action(delegate()
            {
                var i = r.Next();
                Console.WriteLine("Delegate: i = {0}", i);
            });
        action();
    }
```

The following block only exists as C# syntactic sugar to enforce an extra layer of variable scope in the source code, [as discussed in this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500006/what-is-the-purpose-of-anonymous-blocks-in-c-style-languages).

```
        {
            var i = r.Next(); ;
            Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
        }
```

I proved this by decompiling the generated assembly with ILSpy and getting this:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.Next();
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
        Action action = delegate
        {
            int j = r.Next();
            Console.WriteLine("Delegate: i = {0}", j);
        }
        ;
        action();
    }
```

So does this C# construct have a name? If so what is it?

Comment: I'd call it a block, and they are also used in C, eg see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677778/why-enclose-blocks-of-c-code-in-curly-braces

Comment: I wonder what standard they were introduced in.

Comment: in C you mean?  Can't tell you for sure but the first time I saw them being used predates even ANSI C I think.

Comment: @fvu Really? I'd figure that would be a C99 thing. Isn't that when C finally let you declare variables mid code.

Comment: check the accepted answer to question I linked before, this construct was actually used to bypass that restriction in older dialects.  And I think it was in the output of some odd CASE tool that converted Nassi-Shneiderman flowcharts to something that looked more or less like C that I saw them first I think, probably because it reduced the scope the tool had to take into account to manage the vars it generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [statement block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx).

There is actually no difference between a statement block after e.g. an `if (...)` and a statement block that stands alone. A statement block can be used everywhere where a statement can be used.

Comment: @JustinDearing: Any source for "unnamed statement block"? A quick google search returns about 5 results, and none are related to C#. There is really nothing special about a statement block that is not used within statement like `if` or `while`, so I don't  think there is a specific name.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a specific name for the { } used in that specific context, but the name of the thing they introduce is called *[nested scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*.  (Reference also usage of *nested scope* in the [documentation for goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).