# About brackets in C compilation

Tags: c, compilation

I noticed that you can contain random blocks of code in brackets, which localizes all the declared variables inside.

My question is, are these variables freed from the program after the program has left the 'brackets area'? By this I mean, are they created and destroyed on the stack similar to functions?

I tried to look at some dis-assembly to figure it out, but I'm not that good at reading compiler generated assembly ( that should have a stand alone tutorial )

EDIT:

This is what I mean:

```
int main( ){

    {
        int i = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know what functions are. I'm not talking about functions and I'm not asking anyone to tell me what a function is.

Comment: You really should take time to **read a good *C* programming book**. It explains such things much better than we can do in a few minutes.

Comment: why am I getting voted down? I know C, did I miss something basic?

Comment: Reading the generated assembly (if using GCC, don't forget to compile with `gcc -Wall -S -fverbose-asm`) cannot help: the compiler has a lot of freedom about what it can do...

Comment: And I downvoted your question because obviously you did not search enough, e.g. by reading good *C* programming material. Forums are not appropriate for such basic questions, you are expected to learn things first by yourself.

Comment: I'm not talking about functions. I know what functions are.

Comment: I did read your question carefully, I still downvote it, and I am sure you did not study carefully enough your C programming book or course. And you question has no precise meaning: the C99 standard gives the intended meaning of such language constructs, and the implementation is free to implement it. How/When is the variable's location "freed", and how efficient is it, is an implementation detail (which could vary between compilers and between optimization flags given to them).

Comment: okay, I thought I was being misunderstood and I get frustrated when I'm down voted. I'm editing my question so that I ask the question with a little more detail.

Comment: Don't edit the question. Stop typing and start reading good C programming material!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why enclose blocks of C code in curly braces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677778/why-enclose-blocks-of-c-code-in-curly-braces)

Comment: same subject, different question. doesn't matter anyway since someone already answered the question

Comment: FWIW: I had the same question as the OP: *What happens to the automatic variables after leaving their scope **from the machine's point-of-view**?*. I wouldn't expect "a good C programming book" to explicitly mention this (see discussion in Alok's answer), nor anticipate the need for such effort just to answer this one question. I think this is a valid question that just needs re-wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic variables in a nested scope are inaccessible and invalid outside that scope.  Logically, they are destroyed; there's no portable way for you to tell what actually happens to them.  Static variables in the scope could be made accessible outside the scope by assigning a pointer (that's defined outside the scope) that points to the static variable inside the scope.

Limiting the scope of variables makes it easier to understand a program.  You don't have to look elsewhere for places where they're used.  This is similar to making functions static; you don't have to look outside the current source file for uses of them (unless they're used to initialize pointers to functions that are referenced outside the file).  There is usually no run-time efficiency gain.

You might see a benefit with VLAs:

```
{
    int n = 1000;
    {
        int array1[n];
    }
    {
        int array2[n];
    }
}
```

Here, you can reasonably hope that the compiler only allocates space for 1000 integers on the stack; if the arrays were not in separate scopes, it would have to allocate space for 2000 integers on the stack.  (And you might get 'space sharing' with ordinary arrays, or plain variables, if the scopes are disjoint as shown.)

Comment: "Logically, they are destroyed; there's no portable way for you to tell what actually happens to them" - That answers my first question exactly. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

> **Are these variables freed from the program after the program has left the 'brackets area'?**

If the variables are automatic/local variables, Yes they are.

> **Does this make the program any more efficient?**

Probably not, most modern day compilers will optimize the code to the same effect even without the scopes but doing it explicitly makes your code more organized. It is more intuitive for the readers of your code to know the scope within which the variables will be alive and accessible. The code you write is not only for the compiler but for the future users of your code.

---

Each bracket `{` opens a scope which ends with `}`, all local variables declared within the scope remain alive only within that scope.

For eg:

```
void doSomething()
{
   {

       int i;
   }

}
```

`i` lives within the inner scope `{ }` inside the function and does not exist beyond it.
As you can control the **lifetime** and **visibility** of the variables using scope `{ }`, the feature is used for the same.

Comment: I disagree. Implementations are not required to free variables -which does not have any precise meaning. You could even imagine a C (inefficient) interpreter allocating its call frames in some garbage collected heap (see Appel's old paper *Garbage Collection can be faster than stack allocation*) - then you don't know when the "variable is freed" - and still be standard compliant.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: While your point is valid and well made I don't see how it disagrees with anything said in the answer. The answer never said *Implementations need to free variables*, it merely states automatic and logical variables are freed. From the perspective of the user, Yes they are freed. Any use beyond the scope is UB. From perspective of implementation they may or may not be freed but a user of the language should be least bothered of that.

Comment: my point is that "variables are freed" has no precise sense .... Implementations are free to do what they want. From the user's perspective, they are not freed but have disappeared.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You do not take the street which leads to something where you don't want to go, it is as simple as that. So I don't see what difference it makes in saying either.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question if the code will become more efficient: most likely not. Compilers in general will collect all local variables of a function together and locate them in the outer scope. If they see a good reason to break up the stack frame, then they will do that with locals in the outer scope as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here the variable "I" holds its value until control comes out of main() function.

Comment: thanks for answering, but that doesn't seem to be part of my question