# Never before seen syntax in Objective-C: open/close braces w/out method/conditional statement, what is the purpose?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, syntax

I am looking over an Xcode project I downloaded and am seeing code syntax that I am unfamiliar with:

[image]

The braces don't belong to a method signature, or any other conditional statement, they are just floating there. What is the point of this? Purely for code segregation/readability purposes?

Comment: Do you mean that it is outside of a method?

Comment: No, this code is within a method. Was confused about why it would be there, but the below answers make sense.

Comment: Sometimes I'll use this style to group code visually, not for any semantic purpose... And in switch statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just block scope; and is the same in C and C++.  Any variables declared within the block are inaccessible outside of it.  I commonly use it in `switch` statements:

```
switch(x) {
case 1: {
    const char *s = "hi";
}
break;
case 2: {
    const char *s = "ho";
}
break;
// etc.
}
```

Note that there are two variables called `s`, neither of which interfere with the other as they are within their own scope.

Comment: I guess I commonly use it in switch statements as well! Didn't know it could be used anywhere. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Casper Yeah you can, as your question demonstrates, but for me it's not so common.

Comment: it is common to use it with `if` statements too

Answer (score 2):

The declarations within the scope enclosed by the braces will be confined to that scope, so `label`, `icon`, and `button` will not be visible outside of it.  As such it provides locality which is generally considered to be good.

Answer (score 1):

Legacy code needed { } in order to do declarations at all

In C89, you couldn't just do int i; anywhere; declarations were only valid at the beginning of blocks.

check this for more explanation

[Why enclose blocks of C code in curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677778/why-enclose-blocks-of-c-code-in-curly-braces)