# On using several scoped blocks in a C++ function

Tags: c++, function, scope, block

I am starting to be more and more attracted to writing long C++ algorithmic functions using successive scoped blocks, as follows:

```
void my_algorithm(const MyStruct1 &iparam1, MyStruct2 &oparam2)
{
    // First block
    MyStruct3 intermediate_var3;
    {
        double temporary_var;
        // Functional step 1.1
        // Functional step 1.2
        intermediate_var3 = ...
    }
    // Second block
    MyStruct4 intermediate_var4;
    {
        double temporary_var;
        // Functional step 2.1
        // Functional step 2.2
        intermediate_var4 = ...
    }
    // Final block
    {
        int temporary_var;
        oparam2 = ...
    }
}
```

I am starting to think it is a good way to clarify the function structure and to limit the scope of temporary variables (such as counters `i`, `j`, `k` etc). I saw that such scope blocks make sense in C functions to enable new declarations (see [Why enclose blocks of C code in curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677778/why-enclose-blocks-of-c-code-in-curly-braces)).

In the context of C++, is this good or bad practice ?

Comment: That is a smell that you should really extract these blocks as functions. If you think there may be a performance issue you can always inline the functions. Smart compilers usually do this by themselves anyway

Comment: Generally bad, as it's usually a sign that a function is doing too many disparate things. Use separate functions instead.

Comment: You may be right... Still, as these blocks are part of a single _algorithm_, not just any C++ function, does it really make sense to separate them in different functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clear sign, that you should extract this separate blocks into separate functions.

```
MyStruct3 DoSth3(params)
{
    double temporary_var;
    // Functional step 1.1
    // Functional step 1.2
    return ...
}

MyStruct4 DoSth4(params)
{
    double temporary_var;
    // Functional step 2.1
    // Functional step 2.2
    intermediate_var4 = ...
}

void my_algorithm(const MyStruct1 &iparam1, MyStruct2 &oparam2)
{
    // First block
    MyStruct3 intermediate_var3 = DoSth3(params);

    // Second block
    MyStruct4 intermediate_var4 = DoSth4(params);

    int temporary_var;
    oparam2 = ...
}
```

It may happen, that you'll be worried about `DoSth3` and `DoSth4` being public, as they should be private *in the context of my_algorithm*. In such case you can solve it in the following way:

```
class my_algorithm
{
private:
    static MyStruct3 DoSth3(params);
    static MyStruct4 DoSth4(params);

public:
    static void Perform(const MyStruct1 &iparam1, MyStruct2 &oparam2);
};
```

Comment: OK, I guess using a class and private internal functions is the most proper way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: +1 ; instead of the class approach, you can just as well keep the 'private' functions local to the cpp file where the algorithm is in though. I like this more as it achieves the same goal and you're not using a class as a glorified namespace..

Comment: Yes, local functions are a nice idea too. I think that even is the most natural modification to the original way I was writing my function.